# How to add a Spring Boot HealthIndicator to an Imap receiver IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How do you integrate a Spring Boot HealthIndicator with an IntegrationFlow polling email with imap?

I can get exceptions from the IntegrationFlow via the errorChannel but how do I "clear" the exception once the IntegrationFlow starts working again, e.g., after a network outage.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow mailFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(receiver()).get(),
                        e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                                .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000)))
                .channel(mailChannel()).get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ImapMailReceiver receiver() {
        String mailServerPath = format("imaps://%s:%s@%s/INBOX", mailUser,
                encode(mailPassword), mailServer);
        ImapMailReceiver result = new ImapMailReceiver(mailServerPath);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    DirectChannel mailChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("errorChannel")
    private PublishSubscribeChannel errorChannel;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel).handle(message -> {
            MessagingException ex = (MessagingException) message.getPayload();
            log.error("", ex);
        }).get();
    }

    @Bean
    HealthIndicator mailReceiverHealthIndicator() {
        return () -> {
            /*
             * How to error check the imap polling ???
             */
            return Health.up().build();
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with an `AtomicReference<Exception>` bean and set its value in that `errorHandlingFlow`. The `HealthIndicator` impl would consult that `AtomicReference` to `down()` when it has a value.

The `PollerSpec` for the `Mail.imapInboundAdapter()` could be configured with a `ReceiveMessageAdvice`:

```
/**
 * Specify AOP {@link Advice}s for the {@code pollingTask}.
 * @param advice the {@link Advice}s to use.
 * @return the spec.
 */
public PollerSpec advice(Advice... advice) {
```

Its `afterReceive()` impl could just clean that `AtomicReference` up, so your `HealthIndicator` would return `up()`.

The point is that this `afterReceive()` is called only when `invocation.proceed()` doesn't fail with an exception. and it is called independently if there are new messages to process or not.